# Changed selectedindex of DropDownB based on the selectedindex of DropDown A with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two DropDownLists I am working with.

```
<div id="agency">
    <select id="DropDownA">
        <option value="1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="3">Item 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="agency-id">
    <select id="DropDownB">
        <option value="A">Item A</option>
        <option value="B">Item B</option>
        <option value="C">Item C</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The values of the two DropDownLists are different. I need it so that when Item 1 is chosen, Item A is also chosen. When Item 2 is chosen, Item B is chosen.

I tried using this bit of code I found in a similar question, however it only changes DropDownB on time, not repeatedly.

```
$("div#agency select").change(function(){
    $("div#agency-id select")[0].selectedIndex = 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you set it to index `1` everytime - get the index of the first changed select then set it:

```
$("div#agency select").change(function(){
    var index = this.selectedIndex;
    $("div#agency-id select")[0].selectedIndex = index;
});
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I had tried this before in Fiddle but it didn't work. I tried it in my work environment and it works fine. I guess Fiddle was messing up for some reason. Thanks for you help.